# order linq query by descending

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I cannot work out how to get the following query to be distinct by `LatLong` (using the most recent entry):

```
var query = from ent in db.Entrants
            select new { 
                  ent.idx, 
                  ent.LatLong, 
                  ent.Tip, 
                  ent.FirstName, 
                  ent.City, 
                  ent.Fragrance };
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So are you worried about ordering or distinctness?

Comment: basically i just want to most recent entry from each lat long, so i dont get more than one entry per latlong. When a new person enters i want their latlong to be used instead of any others with the same latlong. if that makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var query = from ent in db.Entrants
            //get the most recent entry first
            orderby ent.idx descending
            //group the entries by LatLong so we can get a distinct entry for each latlong
            group ent by ent.LatLong into grouped
            //get the most recent one
            let ent = grouped.First()
            select new 
            { 
                ent.idx, 
                ent.LatLong, 
                ent.Tip, 
                ent.FirstName, 
                ent.City, 
                ent.Fragrance 
            };
```

I wasn't sure which column you wanted to order by to get the most recent entry, so I ordered by idx descending, but you can change that to whatever column you like.

Comment: beauty! thanks, i will accept in 3 mins when SO will allow me to :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
var distinct = query.DistinctBy(x => x.LatLong); // requires MoreLinq
```

or

```
var sorted = query.OrderBy(x => x.LatLong);
```

or combine them:

```
var result = query.DistinctBy(x => x.LatLong).OrderBy(x => x.LatLong);
```

Comment: 'cannot convert lambda expression to type IEquality<Annoymous> because its not a delegate type.' error on the Distinct(x => x.LatLong); bit

Comment: You are right of course; I keep confusing Distinct with DistinctBy. For that you need the MoreLinq library; see http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var retVal = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.LatLong).Distinct(x => x.LatLong);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the anonymous type.

> Because the Equals and GetHashCode methods on anonymous types are
>   defined in terms of the Equals and GetHashcode methods of the
>   properties, two instances of the same anonymous type are equal only if
>   all their properties are equal.
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

Define a proper type with a proper `Equals` method for this, because the `Distinct` calls the standard `Equals` of the nested type.

I've never seen an overload of distinct which receives a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
var groups = db.Entrants.GroupBy(ent => ent.LatLong);
```

will give you an enumeration of *groups*, each of which contains all the entries for a given `LatLong`. Now, I've got no idea how you tell which entry is *most recent*, but if you know they're towards the *end* of `db.Entrants` then you can use

```
var mostRecentPerLatLong = groups.Select(g => g.Last());
```

or if you know they're at the *start* you can use

```
var mostRecentPerLatLong = groups.Select(g => g.First());
```

or maybe it's by `idx` so you can use

```
var mostRecentPerLatLong =
    groups.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(e => e.idx).First());
```

and then you can do your object creation:

```
var query = mostRecentPerLatLong.Select(ent => new { ... } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a grouping

```
from ent in db.Entrants
     group ent by ent.LatLong into grp
     let b = grp.OrderByDescending(x=>x.idx).First();
      select new { 
                  b.idx, 
                  b.LatLong, 
                  b.Tip, 
                  b.FirstName, 
                  b.City, 
                  b.Fragrance 
                };
```